# Fastest way to check whether a uint16 is in range including wrapping on overflow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a range of values from 0 to 65535 (like uint16). The values wrap around if they exceed the boundary, f. e. 65535 + 1 = 0.

What is the **fastest** way to check whether a number x is in a given range(y, y+20)? Where `x` and `y` are in the range of values, but `y+20` could be wrapped. For example when `x = 2` and `y = 65533`, the return value should be `True`.

I'm using Python3 and try to avoid importing any modules. I got already:

```
def test1(num, min):
    r = [x % 2**16-1 for x in range(min, min+20)]
    if num in r:
        return True
    return False

def test2(num, min):
    return True if min <= num < min+20 or min <= num+2**16-1 < min+20 else False
```

`timeit` (one million executions) reports 7.558 s for test1, respectively 1.071 s for test2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first test is *incredibly* inefficient as you are generating a list (populating a section of memory) with loads of integers and then iterating through that whole list just to find if one integer is in it when you could just use numerical tests to check if that number is in that range.

So this explains why your second test is much faster at completing, but  it produces the wrong results in some cases as you should add `2**16` not `2**16-1` as the unsigned system is mod `2**16` (`65536`) not `65535`!

Oh and some Python tips in general. You could have just returned `num in`r`in`test1`(scrap the if-statement) and same in`test`, you could just return the condition. Efficiency-wise, this has basically no impact, but stylistically, saying "true if this statement is true otherwise false" is equivalent to just saying "if this statement".

In conclusion, I would go with:

```
def test(num, min):
    return min <= num < min+20 or min <= num+2**16 < min+20
```

which works as it should:

```
>>> test(32, 20)
True
>>> test(0, 65535)
True
>>> (65535 + 20) % 65536
19
>>> test(18, 65535)
True
```